# Python: grab a value in a list

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner to Python and programming in general.
I'm learning on my own, using web resources.
I'm currently doing an exercise in order to practice, but I need help.
I have a list of objects with 5 items (item 1 to item5).
I need your help to find an item in the list (see below).

```
item_list = ["item1, item2, item3, item4, item5"]

my_item = input("what item do you need ?")

if my_item == item_list[0:4]:

       print(my_item "has been found in the list")
```

Comment: If you are a complete beginner, have a look at some tutorial series or similar. I'm pretty fond of this source which provides an online environment etc. to learn and understand python: [python institute courses](https://pythoninstitute.org/free-python-courses/)
(Not related to the question per se, but just a tip :) )

Comment: You do not have a list of many items - you have a list that contains 1 string (== 1 item). SO does not aim to teach you python, look up tutorials for that. You can use SO as resource - simply googling `python how to find if item in list site:stackoverflow.com` gives you roughly 170k hits that will give you the knowledge you need - no need to post a _new_ question.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick Artner. As I said, I am completely new to it, and I had no clue where to look for, especially when the answers on the web sound even more complex than my question :) It's my very first steps, so all my deep apologies if my question sounds dumb. Also, I have followed the advice of tbjorch, and I am now following the Python institute course. Many thanks to both of you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python has a specific keyword to "check if an it is in list", it's simply called `in`.

Therefore your line could look like:

```
if my_item in item_list:
    ...
```